# Milk bread problem

Tags: bread, milk, japanese-cuisine

Is there a way to reduce a certain amount of milk to replace it with water while still maintaining the richness in milk bread?

Milk is getting majorly expensive and I saw online someone using at least 6.5-8% of milk and the rest of liquids as water/oil

Comment: Maybe get some dried milk powder and make up some milk with it before baking. It's often cheaper than fresh milk. You can just make up what you need, eliminating any waste.

Comment: @BillyKerr That's a good suggestion; I'd write it up as an answer rather than a comment though.